# Como quebrar linha usando StreamWriter?

Tags: c#

Eu tenho esse código que gera um log sempre quando o serviço acaba, porém pode acontecer de ter NF não processadas e preciso listar a mesma pra ficar facil a identificação.

Exemplo 100 NF não foram processadas.
Neste caso está listando tudo na mesma linha ao invés de quebrar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 public void GerarLogoProcessamentoFim()
    {
        StreamWriter objWR = new StreamWriter(processo, true);
        StringBuilder linha = new StringBuilder();
        linha.Append("      --> NF PROCESSADAS: " + processadas);
        linha.Append("      --> NF NÃO PROCESSADAS: " + nprocessadas);
        if (nprocessadasNumero.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < nprocessadasNumero.Count; i++)
            {
                linha.Append("NF - " + nprocessadasNumero[i]);
            }
        }
        linha.Append("      <-- FINALIZAÇÃO:" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
        objWR.WriteLine(linha.ToString());
        objWR.Close();
    }
```

Comment: só usar o caractere para nova linha: `\n` exemplo:  `linha.Append("NF - " + nprocessadasNumero[i] + "\n");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por que não usas

```
objWR.Write(string)
```

e

```
objWR.WriteLine(string)
```

em vez de montar uma linha em um StringBuilder e imprimir, no final do laço, dentro de `objWR`? No final das contas, é no `objWR` que você quer saída, então eu usava métodos desse.

Answer (score 1):

Write, escreve sem pular linha e WriteLine, escreve a linha e pula

**objWR.WriteLine(string)**

Ou

Essas duas abaixo se equivalem, se você debuggar verá que essa **Environment.NewLine é "/r/n"**:

linha.Append(Environment.NewLine);
OU
linha.Append("/r/n");

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar:

```
linha.AppendLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
linha.Append(Environment.NewLine);
```